# c# linq question

Tags: c#, linq

I have a data table and I want to select all distinct names from the result. I wrote following linq query for it.

```
var distinctRows = (from DataRow myDataRow in myDataTable.Rows 
                    select new { col1 = myDataRow ["Name"]}).Distinct();
```

Now how can I iterate through distinctRows? Seems like I cannot do `foreach(DataRow Row in distinctRows)`, It gives me "Cannot convert type 'AnonymousType#1' to 'System.Data.DataRow'" error

Comment: In the future, you'll probably get better results if the title of the question describes your question. "C# linq question" tells us nothing; C# and linq are already the tags, and we know its a question.

Comment: @Eric, Thanks for pointing it out. Sorry for using stupid title :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're only selecting one field, you don't need an anonymous type here. Just select the names and then iterate over the distinct ones. To wit:

```
var distinctNames = (from DataRow myDataRow in myDataTable.Rows
                     select myDataRow.Field<string>("Name")
                    ).Distinct();

foreach(var name in distinctNames) {
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Note that the error makes it very clear what the problem is here. You are trying to convert an instance of an anonymous type to an instance of `DataRow` and that is impossible. Without changing your code, you could iterate this as

```
foreach(var item in distinctRows) {
    Console.WriteLine((string)item.col1);
}
```

But I would change this as per the above as you don't need the anonymous type and your variable names and field names are poor.

Answer (score 2):

Those aren't DataRows; they're anonymous objects.
To loop through them, you need to declare the variable using the `var` keyword.

However, there's no point in the anonymous type in the first place.
You can change your query to `select myDataRow.Field<string>("Name")` to get a set of strings.

Comment: Why do you need an example?  If you actually read the error, the solution should be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the keyword `var` to refer to anonymous types (which is what you're returning an `IEnumerable<>` of).

```
foreach(var row in distinctRows)
{
    // do something with each anonymous type instance
}
```

Since you're only returning anonymous types with one string property however, you may as well project an `IEnumerable<string>`

Answer (score 0):

That's because `myDataRow["Name"]` doesn't return a `DataRow`. Try

```
foreach(var item in distinctRows) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the return value isn't a DataRow. It's an ad-hoc type that containes the property col1.

Answer (score 0):

To build on SLaks answer . . .

```
var distinctRows = (from DataRow myDataRow in myDataTable.Rows 
                    select new { col1 = myDataRow ["Name"]}).Distinct();

foreach(var row in distinctRows)
{
    System.Console.Writeline(row.col1);  //should work fine
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're selecting a new anonymous type by doing `select new { col1 = myDataRow ["Name"]}` and not the actual row itself.  So when you try to iterate this as DataRow, it will error out because your anonymous type being selected is not of type DataRow.

If you want to be able to select a whole data row and not just the name field, you will need to implement a custom [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) for data row to pass to the Distinct() extension method.

An example would be:

```
public class NameComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
{
    public bool Equals(DataRow left, DataRow right)
    {
        return left.Field<string>("Name").Equals(right.Field<string>("Name"));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DataRow obj)
    {
        return obj.ToString().GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then using it:

```
var distinctRows = (from DataRow myDataRow in myDataTable.Rows 
                    select myDataRow).Distinct(new NameComparer());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also foreach them but first you had to List them as the following :

```
List<string> rslt =(from DataRow myDataRow in myDataTable.Rows 
                    select new { col1 = myDataRow ["Name"].ToString()}).Distinct().ToList();

foreach(string str in rlst)
{}
```

Hope this helped